# highcharts-export-server always produces blank PNG

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to use highcharts-export-server in command-line/batch mode. I've installed the latest version (2.0.28). I'm running Windows 10 with Node 12.

I'm running it from the command line using the following command:

```
highcharts-export-server --nologo 1 --logLevel 4 --options chart.json --outfile chart.png --type png --width 500
```

The console output says:

```
starting highcharts export server v2.0.28...
Fri Sep 25 2020 15:07:48 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) [verbose] attaching exit listeners to the process..
Fri Sep 25 2020 15:07:48 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) [verbose] Pool started:
maxWorkers: 1
initialWorkers: 1
workLimit: 60
listening to process exit: true
Fri Sep 25 2020 15:07:48 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) [verbose] phantom 1 - spawning worker
Fri Sep 25 2020 15:07:48 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) [verbose] starting export
Fri Sep 25 2020 15:07:48 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) [verbose] attempting to export from raw input
Fri Sep 25 2020 15:07:48 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) [verbose] phantom - received work, finding available worker
Fri Sep 25 2020 15:07:48 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) [verbose] phantom - found available worker
Fri Sep 25 2020 15:07:48 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) [verbose] phantom 1 - starting work
Fri Sep 25 2020 15:07:52 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) [notice] phantom worker 1 finished work ??? in 3562 ms
Fri Sep 25 2020 15:07:52 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) [notice] phantom worker 1 - process was closed
Fri Sep 25 2020 15:07:52 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) [notice] terminating, killing all running phantom processes
```

...but although a `chart.png` file is created and has the correct width, it's blank (transparent):
[image]

This is the content of the `chart.json` file, which I took from one of the examples on the Highcharts website:

```
{
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
    }]
}
```

---

Note: I'll mention that when I first tried to install highcharts-export-server I hit a different problem which was that I couldn't run it at all (it failed with `uncaughtException: TypeError: "file" argument must be a non-empty string`). After some googling I found some blog posts suggesting that I needed to install PhantomJS first, and to use the --unsafe-perm option. So, the commands I actually used to install it was:

```
npm install phantomjs --unsafe-perm
npm install highcharts-export-server --unsafe-perm
```

Oh, and it wasn't until some time later that I realised I might have to install Highcharts itself :-) So I did that too (`npm install highcharts`), but it didn't actually seem to make a difference.

Comment: If you're exporting to a chart through the CMD, use the --infile instead of the --options argument (highcharts-export-server --nologo 1 --logLevel 4 --infile chart.json --outfile chart.png --type png --width 500). When it comes to PhantomJS issue, it shouldn't be a problem when it's not found as it should download automatically. As for installing the Highcharts package separately, it is only needed when you consider using a version installed locally instead of downloading from the CDN (the default option).

Comment: @pawel_d: Thanks, but using --infile rather than --options seems to make no difference.

Comment: The --options argument should be used only when the input is specified as a string, while the --infile when the input is a JSON file that contains chart options. I would get rid of the standalone phantomjs package and make sure that the server is installed and configured correctly, as described here: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server. Also, try to generate a basic chart (e.g. https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/blob/master/testcharts/basic.json) and see if the problems still occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this helps anyone else, here is the [full conversation](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=45062&p=160642) about this issue on the Highcharts Forum.

In summary, it turned out that the NPM package was improperly installed (due to a firewall issue).

This wasn't apparent from the installation logs, but the effect was that in the `node_modules/highcharts/export-server/phantom/export.html` file there was a script block that *should* have contained minified JavaScript but that actually contained only lines saying `undefined;`.

The fix in my case (to work around the firewall issue) was to specify an `http` URL for the CDN when installing Highcharts Export Server, rather than the default URL which uses `https`. Once I'd done that, the `export.html` did contain the minified JS code, and the tool worked correctly.